# Unable to send mail from Ruby on Rails 4.2 task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I can deliver a mailer from rails console, but the same mailer is not being sent from a rake task

This is my `environments/development.rb`

```
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'my.mail.server',
    port: 465,
    user_name: "my-account",
    password: "my-password",
    athentication: :plain,
    ssl: true
  }
```

Mailer:

```
class ScriptAlertMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def alert_email(to)
    mail(to: to, subject: 'This is an alert').deliver
  end  
end
```

Task:

```
task :inspect_js => :environment do
  puts "running inspect_js"
  ScriptAlertMailer.alert_email "mymail@domain.com"
end
```

The mail is being sent in `rails console`. No matter whether loaded in development or production environments:

```
ScriptAlertMailer.alert_email "an-account@domain.com"
```

Outputs the rendered mailer view in log/[environment].log then is sent.

But when I do it with `rake inspect_js` nothing is appended to log and is not sent

I've tried with `deliver, deliver!, deliver_later and deliver_now` with no luck

Any thoughts?

Comment: I've never seen `deliver` within the mailer.  I would try `ScriptAlertMailer.alert_email("mymail@domain.com").deliver_now`, taking the deliver out of the mailer.  Could be wrong but you would need to do `logger.info "running inspect_js"` rather than puts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deliver` method should not be called within the mailer itself. In rails console, you are seeing the `Mail::Message` object, but I don't think any actual email is being sent. The changes below should get your task to work.

In the mailer, change:

```
mail(to: to, subject: 'This is an alert').deliver
```

To:

```
mail(to: to, subject: 'This is an alert')
```

In the rake task, change:

```
ScriptAlertMailer.alert_email "mymail@domain.com"
```

To:

```
ScriptAlertMailer.alert_email("mymail@domain.com").deliver_now
```